# backbonejs model.save's create or update - can't get the update request

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, requirejs

Why can't I get the **update** request in `model.save`? I always get **create** request.

view,

```
define([
    // load the dependencies
], function(App, $, _, Backbone, Handlebars, ProjectModel, ProjectCollection){

    var updateFormView = Backbone.View.extend({

        el: 'div.abPanel', 

        initialize: function () {
            $(this.el).undelegate('form#frmAddContact', 'submit'),
            _.bindAll(this, 'updateContactPage', 'updateContact');
        }, 


        events: {
            'submit form#frmAddContact': 'updateContact'
        }, 

        updateContactPage: function (id) {

            // load the data into the update form

        },

        updateContact: function (event) {

            var contactmodel = new ProjectModel({
                form: $('#frmAddContact', this.$el)
            });

            contactmodel.save();
            return false;
        }
    });

    return updateFormView;
});
```

Model,

```
var ProjectModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        sync: function (method, model, options) {
            console.log(method); // Why I always get create method??
            // other stuff
        }
    });


    return ProjectModel;
});
```

In backbone's [doc](http://documentcloud.github.io/backbone/#Model-save),

> notice how our overridden version of Backbone.sync receives a "create"
>   request the first time the model is saved and an "update" request the
>   second time.

`second time`? I don't get it - why do we need to get the "update" reques at the`second time`? Can't I just get the particular model data from the collection, edit it and update it?

**EDIT:**

```
updateContactPage: function (id) {

            var contact = {};
            var model;


            if(App.contactCollection !== undefined) 
                 model = App.contactCollection.get(id); // I have called the model first time right???


            if (id !== undefined && model !== undefined) {

                console.log(model); // And I get the requested model displayed on my form.
                contact = model.toJSON();
            }
            this.$el.html(Handlebars.getTemplate('add')({contact: contact}));

        },
```

Comment: Are you setting an `id` attribute on the `Backbone.Model` in question?

Comment: Yes I have. please take a look on my edit above. I have called the model in the collection for the first time. Unless I understand it wrong what first and second times meant by backbone???

Comment: The first time, is translated into a `PUT` request (i.e. you `save` a model that doesn't have `id` attribute). The second time is translated into a `POST` request (i.e. you `save` a model with an `id` attribute). In short `App.contactCollection.get(id) != (first time || second time)`.

Comment: do you mean it should look like this - `contactmodel.save(id);`?

Comment: To get the update request, I only have to set/ send an id to the model. So I got it fixed finally. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To get the `update` request, I only have to set/ send an id to the model,

```
updateContact: function (event) {

            var contactmodel = new ProjectModel({
                id:38, // set an id here for updating
                form: $('#frmAddContact', this.$el)
            });

            contactmodel.save();
            return false;
        }
```